# How to set two button properly to each other in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I need to set two buttons side by side... I have used `linearlayout` for it... I have given each button to `0.5` `layout_weight` as i want each one to take equal space..I also make button to take equal `height`. The problem i am facing that left button will **slide down** if i give right button to match its height.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/botomMarginTextView"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back"
        android:text="@string/name1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back"
        android:text="@string/name2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Edit :

> Please give left button longer text and right button smaller
>   text..otherwise it is producing right layout

I am using `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` . If i am going with normal theme then it is working fine

Now how to make this button keep side by side and also to make them of equal height?

Comment: Post the XML snippet.

Comment: Have you set the parrent for the buttons to have a WeightSum of 1 and the buttons height to 0dp?

Comment: weightSum is **optional**. Android calculates it by itself.

Comment: this XML snippet giving me absolutely correct output...you can try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `android:layout_height` attribute of `LinearLayout`, give value of `60dp`

```
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

and to `android:layout_height` attribute of both `Button`, give value of `match_parent`

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

So, updated XML snippet will be

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/botomMarginTextView"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back"
        android:text="@string/name1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back"
        android:text="@string/name2" />
</LinearLayout>
```